# Why can't I change the name for my Google Calendar in Apple's Calendar app?

Tags: google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business, integration

I've got several Google personal and Google Workspace accounts and have all of them connected to my Apple Calendar client. For all of these — except one — I'm able to change the name for the calendar in my Calendar app. The exception keeps reverting to my have a name corresponding to my e-mail for the linked Google account. I've checked settings and they all match those for accounts where I can change the calendar name.

What could be forcing the name I proved in my Apple Calendar client to revert to the e-mail for that account? Is there a setting I'm missing in my Google account or the corresponding Google Workspace?